# how to delete specific object from nested array of objects recursively?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

data :

```
    var data = [ 
   { 
      "name":"list1",
      "type":"list",
      "id":1,
      "child":[ 
         { 
            "name":"list2",
            "type":"subList",
            "id":2,
            "child":[ 
               { 
                  "name":"list3",
                  "type":"subList",
                  "id":3
               },
               { 
                  "name":"list4",
                  "type":"list",
                  "id":4,
                  "child":[ 
                     { 
                        "name":"list5",
                        "type":"list",
                        "id":5
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         { 
            "name":"list6",
            "type":"subList",
            "id":6
         }
      ]
   },
   { 
      "name":"list I",
      "type":"list",
      "id":7
   }
]
```

I need to remove **"id": 5** form this data, I tried this :

```
data.filter(function f(o) {
  return o.id !== 5 ||
         o.child && (o.child.filter(f)).length
})
```

Final output would be without id:5, In some cases the first list id:1 also can be erasable. Hot to simplify this recursively It may have N no of children list, have to loop through every list and delete it?

Comment: So if a child have the ID you wanna erase, the parent should be deleted ? or just the child ?

Comment: if a parent contains deleted item , I need to show alert to confirm the user to delete both parent and child

Answer (score 4):

There is no easy (non-hacky) way to remove the element without looping through the arrays.

You need to first filter the data array, then map over the remaining entries and filter their `child` property recursively, e.g.:

```js
function removeIdDeep(data, idToRemove) {
  const filtered = data.filter(entry => entry.id !== idToRemove);
  return filtered.map(entry => {
    if(!entry.child) return entry;
    return {...entry, child: removeIdDeep(entry.child, idToRemove)};
  });
}
```

```js
var data = [ { "name":"list1", "type":"list", "id":1, "child":[ { "name":"list2", "type":"subList", "id":2, "child":[ { "name":"list3", "type":"subList", "id":3 }, { "name":"list4", "type":"list", "id":4, "child":[ { "name":"list5", "type":"list", "id":5 } ] } ] }, { "name":"list6", "type":"subList", "id":6 } ] }, { "name":"list I", "type":"list", "id":7 } ];

function removeIdDeep(data, idToRemove) {
  const filtered = data.filter(entry => entry.id !== idToRemove);
  return filtered.map(entry => {
    if(!entry.child) return entry;
    return {...entry, child: removeIdDeep(entry.child, idToRemove)};
  });
}

console.log(removeIdDeep(data, 5));
```

Edit: If you want to prompt the user before removing elements, you can just add the `confirm` prompt to the filter:

```js
var data = [ { "name":"list1", "type":"list", "id":1, "child":[ { "name":"list2", "type":"subList", "id":2, "child":[ { "name":"list3", "type":"subList", "id":3 }, { "name":"list4", "type":"list", "id":4, "child":[ { "name":"list5", "type":"list", "id":5 } ] } ] }, { "name":"list6", "type":"subList", "id":6 } ] }, { "name":"list I", "type":"list", "id":7 } ];

function removeIdDeep(data, idToRemove) {
  const filtered = data.filter(entry => {
    if(entry.id === idToRemove) {
      const numChilds = entry.childs ? entry.childs.length : 0;
      return !confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete ${entry.name}? It contains ${numChilds} children.`);
    }
    return true;
  });
  return filtered.map(entry => {
    if(!entry.child) return entry;
    return {...entry, child: removeIdDeep(entry.child, idToRemove)};
  });
}

console.log(removeIdDeep(data, 5));
```

If you want to display some custom warning, you'll have to first find the element, display the warning and only then call `removeIdDeep`.

Comment: can't understand why we need this  return {...entry, child: removeIdDeep(entry.child, idToRemove)}; instead just return removeIdDeep(entry.child, idToRemove)

Comment: @Learntocode it will duplicate the entry and replace the child property with `removeIdDeep(entry.child, idToRemove)` - if you just return the last part your result will just be nested arrays except the leaf nodes ([heres a playground](https://repl.it/repls/PaltryGrotesquePascal) to play around with it)

Comment: Thanks. if a parent item should be deleted one, but it contains child, in that case I should indicate a user saying like child also will be deleted.

Comment: @Learntocode i added a small example how you could add a `confirm` prompt to let the user confirm deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recurse function that applies the filter for each `child` array like this:

```
const filterData = (el) => {
  if(el.id === 5) {
    return false
  }

  if(el.child) {
    el.child = el.child.filter(filterData)
  }

  return true
}

const filtered = data.filter(filterData)
```

```js
var data = [ 
   { 
      "name":"list1",
      "type":"list",
      "id":1,
      "child":[ 
         { 
            "name":"list2",
            "type":"subList",
            "id":2,
            "child":[ 
               { 
                  "name":"list3",
                  "type":"subList",
                  "id":3
               },
               { 
                  "name":"list4",
                  "type":"list",
                  "id":4,
                  "child":[ 
                     { 
                        "name":"list5",
                        "type":"list",
                        "id":5
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         { 
            "name":"list6",
            "type":"subList",
            "id":6
         }
      ]
   },
   { 
      "name":"list I",
      "type":"list",
      "id":7
   }
]

const filterData = (el) => {
  if(el.id === 5) {
    return false
  }
  
  if(el.child) {
    el.child = el.child.filter(filterData)
  }
  
  return true
}

const filtered = data.filter(filterData)
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: bad solution, it will change child prop in original objects

Comment: @DmitryReutov you can also use spread operator (like you suggesting in your answer) to get a temp array of `data` like this `[...data].filter(filterData)`

Comment: It's not *meaningless*, it's called *array cloning* and you'll do that to avoid altering the original array, if of course the OP cares about it which it seems like he's not. So, since the OP does simple want to delete these specific elements, then it does not matter if the original array is altered or not, thus my solution even without cloning isn't bad.

Comment: The problem with cloning object, with array there's no problem

Answer (score 0):

Not to change child directly, better spread

```
deleteObject = (arr, id) => {
   return arr
      .filter(elem => elem.id !== id)
      .map(elem => elem.child 
           ? {
         ...elem,
         child: deleteObject(elem.child, id)
      } : elem)   
}
```

Comment: can you explain {
         ...elem,
         child: deleteObject(elem.child, id)
      }  this line please

Comment: @Learntocode we spread the element not to change the original one, so you will get a copy of original array without deleted elements, but the original one will remain as it is